# Regular Expressions in BASH?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am ok with regular expressions in Perl but not had to do it in BASH before.

I tried to google for some sort of tutorial on it but didn't see any really good ones yet the way there are with Perl.

What I am trying to achieve is to strip `/home/devtestdocs/devtestdocs-repo/` out of a variable called `$filename` and replace it with another variable called `$testdocsdirurl`

Hopefully that makes sense and if anybody has any good links that would be much appreciated.

Another way might be is if there is already a function someone has written to do a find and replace in bash.

Comment: I don't see the need for regular expressions here. Can you explain why you think you need them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) is the typical weapon of choice for string manipulation in Unix:

```
echo $filename | sed s/\\/home\\/devtestdocs\\/devtestdocs-repo\\//$testdocsdirurl/
```

Also, as hop suggests, you can use the `@` syntax to avoid escaping the path:

```
echo $filename | sed s@/home/devtestdocs/devtestdocs-repo/@$testdocsdirurl@
```

Comment: sed typically also understands s@pattern@string@ so you don't have to painfully escape slashes in a path.

Comment: @JG,@hop   just to set the record straight - sed will actually take any character you like... so that even a silly expression like this will work `echo SSSSS | sed 'sqSqsqg'`

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this without a regular expression:

```
somepath="/foo/bar/baz"
newprefix="/alpha/beta/"
newpath="$newprefix${somepath##/foo/bar/}"
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, bash supports regular expressions, e.g.

```
$ [[ 'abc' =~ (.)(.)(.) ]]
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
a
$ echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
b
```

but you might rather want to use `basename` utility

```
$ f='/some/path/file.ext'
$ echo "/new/path/$(basename $f)"
/new/path/file.ext
```

excellent source of info is bash manual page

Answer (score 1):

With bash

```
pattern=/home/devtestdocs/devtestdocs-repo/
testdocsdirurl=/tmp/
filename=/foo/bar/home/devtestdocs/devtestdocs-repo/filename
echo ${filename/$pattern/$testdocsdirurl}  # => /foo/bar/tmp/filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need regular expressions for this?

These are just a few possibilities:

```
$ filename=/home/devtestdocs/devtestdocs-repo/foo.txt
$ echo ${filename/'/home/devtestdocs/devtestdocs-repo/'/'blah/'}
blah/foo.txt
$ basename $filename
foo.txt
$ realfilename=$(basename "$filename")
```

Comment: see also: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: thanks, I just thought that using a regular expression would be the way to go on this one.

Comment: @martincarlin87: a good rule of thumb is: regex should be the _last_ way you should go about solving any problem.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for an example of how use regular expressions in powershell?

is there an example here:

```
$input = "hello,123"
$pattern = ([regex]"[0-9]+")
$match = $pattern.match($input)
$ok = $input -match $pattern #return an boolean value if matched..
if($ok) { 
    $output = $match.groups[0].value
    [console]::write($output)
 } else {
   //no match
 }
```

in 'bash classic' regular expressions usage is precarious. 
you can use this:
http://www.robvanderwoude.com/findstr.php

Comment: He asked for the UNIX shell `bash` (Bourne Again SHell), not for batch files or the Window PowerShell.